# Should I use an empty List or make it an Option?

Tags: list, scala, optional-parameters

Often my methods have a `List` parameter that is optional. When I receive a list of items I do something with them, otherwise that parameter is ignored. Here's a trivial example.

```
scala> def convertToUpper(s: String, appenders: List[String] = List()) {
  (s.toUpperCase :: appenders).mkString(" ")
}

scala> convertToUpper("cory", List("asks", "questions"))
CORY asks questions
```

But sometimes I wonder if this contract communicates an expectation of a `appenders` parameter when really it is optional. On the other hand, making `appenders` an `Option[List]` adds complexity.

Is it bad practice to avoid use of `Option` when the parameter is a `List` and I can just test for emptiness instead of `None`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If an empty list is a valid argument (which it is in your example) and it behaves as `None` would, then I would recommend not wrapping the list in an option.

I'd say that wrapping it in an option signals that `None` and `List()` would be treated differently.

I think it's fairly common for methods that accept lists as argument to behave as a no-op.